# How to POST many different field names in RestSharp?

Tags: c#, rest, api, post, restsharp

how I can POST many different field names in RestSharp? 
Below is the code I have tried , will it be like this or other way.
Any help here will be appreciated.

```
JObject jsonPOST = new JObject();

jsonPOST.Add("VariableName1", "temp1" );

jsonPOST.Add("VariableName2", "temp2" );



JObject jsonPOST1 = new JObject();

jsonPOST1.Add("VariableName1", "temp1" );

jsonPOST1.Add("VariableName2", "temp2" );


JObject jsonPOST2 = new JObject();

jsonPOST1.Add("number1", "2" );

jsonPOST1.Add("number2", "4" );

restRequest.AddParameter("application/json", jsonPOST , ParameterType.RequestBody);
restRequest.AddParameter("application/json", jsonPOST1 , ParameterType.RequestBody);
restRequest.AddParameter("application/json", jsonPOST2 , ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

how to POST the data like this with the above RestSharp structure??

I want this format the POST Request that will be sent to the REST Api.

```
"{

"FieldName1":{

"VariableName1": "temp1",

"VariableName2": "temp2",

},

"FieldName2":{

"VariableName1": "temp1",

"VariableName2": "temp2",

},

"FieldName3": {

"number1": "2",

"number2": "4",

}

}"
```

Comment: Please first fix C# and Json Syntax. and change your c# string to fit json one.

Comment: @CorrM help if you can please, I dont know how

Comment: just try to fit names on c# and Json. i can't get the struct layout.

Comment: @CorrM i edited my question,   I dont know how to code the  FieldNames ,  i can put the parameters but I want it in one json with many field names

Comment: @CorrM Because I want to have ,for example ,the "VariableName1" many times, and etc..,  i think that you got what I mean

Comment: Any help here would be appreciated , If anyone can help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine all your `JObject` on one `JObject`.

```
// Main JObject
var mainObj = new JObject();

// Syntax i love
var obj1 = new JObject
{
    {"name", "CorrM"},
    {"ip", "127.0.0.1"}
};

// Syntax are accepted too
var obj2 = new JObject();
obj2.Add("bla1", "bla");
obj2.Add("bla2", "bla");

// Combine on one JObject
mainObj.Add("FieldName1", obj1);
mainObj.Add("FieldName2", obj2);
```

Then add to body (Convert to string).
(i don't know that the correct way to set the Body or not)

```
restRequest.AddParameter("application/json", mainObj.ToString(Formatting.None), ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Output string must looks like that

```
{
  "FieldName1": {
    "name": "CorrM",
    "ip": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "FieldName2": {
    "bla1": "bla",
    "bla2": "bla"
  }
}
```

Comment: Also do you know how to retrieve the values that have the same name from the Rest API json answer that have the same format with that , that was sent to it?(I am talking about the above format that you sent).                                              For example , the values of field1 and field2 ?

Comment: u can convert it back to JObject. [example](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonObject.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but as far as the link that you sent (example) is concerned, what if I have two values with the name CPU or Drives?

Comment: This is what Im asking , what if I have in the same json answer in different Fields variables with the same names?

Comment: As i know it's impossible to get two vars with same name in same Scope in Json. May be u talk about [JArray](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) .?